# Powershell WinSCP won't move it

Tags: powershell, winscp

here is my script:

```
$Path = "G:\FTP\APX\APXDropoff\Pay"
$Archive = "G:\FTP\APX\APXDropoff\Pay\Archive"
#$BankOfTulsa = "H:\Documentation\Projects\PJ\BankOfTulsa"
#$compareDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)


$LastFile = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Where{$_.Name -Match "^CPdb(\d{6})(\d{8}).txt"}; $LastFile

CP $LastFile $Archive

#Call WinSCP Navigate to Incoming\Temp folder for test.
# & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com' /command "option batch abort" "option confirm off" "open sftp:BankOfTulsa/" "put $LastFile /incoming/arp/"
```

So here's my issue. I am using reg ex to find the file the CP moves it just fine but when I go to upload to winSCP it says the file doesn't exist.

And it calls it by name, so the variable is there...

```
Authenticating with pre-entered password.
Authenticated.
Starting the session...
Reading remote directory...
Session started.
Active session: [1] BankOfAmerica
File or folder 'CPdb08131408252014.TXT' does not exist.
System Error.  Code: 2.

The system cannot find the file specified
(A)bort, (R)etry, (S)kip, Ski(p) all: Abort
```

Please help!!

Comment: I would think you should use the full path of `$LastFile` so it would be `"put $($LastFile.FullName) /incoming/arp/"`

Comment: Side note: As you seem to be doing some advanced scripting with WinSCP in PowerShell, you would better do with [WinSCP .NET assembly](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library).

Comment: Yea i originally tried that but I guess my version of WinSCP (on a server with limited access) does not have a WinSCP.dll, which is the first part of the example they use...thanks tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that your issue would lie in that `$LastFile` does not contain the full path of the file you are trying to upload. I would suggest you use the `.FullName` property of `$LastFile` since you have that from the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet.

```
"put $($LastFile.FullName) /incoming/arp/"
```

Also please refrain from using aliases where you can as some people might not know that `CP` is an alias for `Copy-Item`

**Afterthought**

`$lastFile` has the potential to match more that one file. If that is the case it would make a mess of the rest of the script potentially.

From your comment you can do the following:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Where{$_.Name -Match "^CPdb(\d{6})(\d{8}).txt"} |
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

Comment: I plan on doing a comparison on the LastWriteTime to get the most recent file, but I think you're right.

Comment: You would find almost the same solution on WinSCP's [Downloading the most recent file](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file#library) article, just with `Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1`. This approach is probably slightly more efficient, so I have updated the article to use it. Thanks.